# d3.js d3.select($child) from other html class

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a html file that shows several d3.js graphs.
The graphs are generated in a separated js file.

Both Charts are the same, they only have different content. And of course they have to appear at different positions.

So instead of the `d3.select(".chart")` what can i do to address the callers section?

html:

```
<div class="row">....
    <div class="content">
        <svg id="chart" onload="visuHandler('lineChart','userActivity');" />....
</div>

<div class="row">....
    <div class="content">
        <svg id="chart" onload="visuHandler('lineChart','cashflow');" />....
</div>
```

JS:

```
var visuHandler = function (chrt, data) {
    d3.select(".chart")
        .datum(interpretation(data, section))
        .call(chart);
```

Comment: If you have two tags with the same id in the same file you have an invalid file. That seems to be the case here with the svg tags which both have an id of "chart"

Comment: that is a problem indeed. But is it possible to address d3.js selects to other elements than id?

Comment: Yes, it's just a CSS selector so CSS selection syntax applies.

Comment: yeah, but i only want one (generic) method that is generating a chart at the different positions

Comment: Mhy not create each chart with a unique id by passing the id into your generic method. Then select on that id.

Comment: The method to select unique elements is to select by ID as they are supposed to be unique. By design classes concern groups of elements, ids concern single elements. You should work with these conventions.